# Creating new JSF web application with Majorra 2.2.13

Tags: eclipse, jsf, icefaces, eclipse-wtp, mojarra

Following the ICEfaces tutorial [Creating new Eclipse Project without plugin](http://www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/ICE/Creating+New+Eclipse+Project+without+Plugin) I:

- downloaded latest free IDEfaces 4.1.1
- opened the new project wizard "Dynamic Web Project"
- selected JSF 2.2 on the first wizard page
- on the page "JSF Capabilities" I added Mojarra 2.2.13 jar provided with IDEfaces 4.1.1 to my new User Library.
- But the wizard page didn't accept my new user library complaining

> Required class javax.faces.FactoryFinder does not exist in selected libraries.

Looking into the jar, there is no problem to find this class. It's there!

If I select Mojarra 2.2.0 library I can complete the wizard without any further problems. But the ICEfaces web page states explicitly, that the Mojarra version should exact match the version expected by ICEfaces. And this is 2.2.13.

- How can I workaround this issue?
- Should I use other Mojarra or IDEfaces versions?